# ElasticSearch: Perform KNN Search on multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have indexed data into ElasticSearch using the following index settings:

```
KNN_INDEX = {
    "settings": {
        "index.knn": True,
        "index.knn.space_type": "cosinesimil",
        "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 10000,
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "default": {
              "type": "standard",
              "stopwords": "_english_"
            }
          }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
            {
                "sentence_vector_template": {
                    "match": "para_vec_*",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "knn_vector",
                        "dimension": 384,
                        "store": True
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "sentence_template": {
                    "match": "paragraph_*",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "store": True
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        'properties': {
            "metadata": {
                "type": "object"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following are a couple of example documents that I am indexing into ElasticSearch:

```
{
    # DOC 1
    "paragraph_0": "Machine learning for aquatic plastic litter detection, classification and quantification (APLASTIC-Q)Large quantities of mismanaged plastic waste are polluting and threatening the health of the blue planet."
    "para_vec_0" : [ ... ] # Embedding vector for paragraph_0
    "paragraph_1": "As such, vast amounts of this plastic waste found in the oceans originates from land."
    "para_vec_1" : [ ... ] # Embedding vector for paragraph_1
    "paragraph_2": "It finds its way to the open ocean through rivers, waterways and estuarine systems."
    "para_vec_2" : [ ... ] # Embedding vector for paragraph_2
},
{
    # DOC 2
    "paragraph_0": "What predicts persistent early conduct problems?"
    "para_vec_0" : [ ... ] # Embedding vector for paragraph_0
    "paragraph_1": "Evidence from the Growing Up in Scotland cohortBackground There is a strong case for early identification of factors predicting life-course-persistent conduct disorder."
    "para_vec_1" : [ ... ] # Embedding vector for paragraph_1
    "paragraph_2": "The authors aimed to identify factors associated with repeated parental reports of preschool conduct problems."
    "para_vec_2" : [ ... ] # Embedding vector for paragraph_2
    "paragraph_3": "Method Nested caseecontrol study of Scottish children who had behavioural data reported by parents at 3, 4 and 5 years."
    "para_vec_3" : [ ... ] # Embedding vector for paragraph_3
    "paragraph_4": "Results 79 children had abnormal conduct scores at all three time points ('persistent conduct problems') and 434 at one or two points ('inconsistent conduct problems')."
    "para_vec_4" : [ ... ] # Embedding vector for paragraph_4

}
```

There can be different number of paragraphs for each indexed document. For querying, I want to search over all paragraphs over all documents. I am able to search over a particular "paragraph number" in all documents using the below query:

```
    query_body = {
        "size": 50,
        "query": {
            "knn": {
                "para_vec_0": {
                    "vector": query_vector[0].tolist(),
                    "k": 50
                }
            }
        },
        "_source": {
            "exclude": ["para_vec_*"]
        },
    }

    result = client.search(index=INDEX_NAME, body=query_body)
```

But what I am looking for is something like below:

```
    query_body = {
        "size": 50,
        "query": {
            "knn": {
                "para_vec_0": {
                    "vector": query_vector[0].tolist(),
                    "k": 50
                },
                "para_vec_1": {
                    "vector": query_vector[0].tolist(),
                    "k": 50
                }
            }
        },
        "_source": {
            "exclude": ["para_vec_*"]
        },
    }

    result = client.search(index=INDEX_NAME, body=query_body)
```

OR

```
    query_body = {
        "size": 50,
        "query": {
            "knn": {
                "para_vec_*": {
                    "vector": query_vector[0].tolist(),
                    "k": 50
                }
            }
        },
        "_source": {
            "exclude": ["para_vec_*"]
        },
    }

    result = client.search(index=INDEX_NAME, body=query_body)
```

The above queries do not work though. Is is possible perform such a query search ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, which version of elasticsearch are you using ?

Comment: Well actually, I don't think it matters, I am not sure this is yet possible